# Power management : "do nothing" when laptop is closed

Tags: release-freya, power

In Freya there is no way to specify an action for *What to do when the laptop lid is closed* (eg *do nothing*, *hibernate*, *turn off* etc.)

Unfortunately when I close my laptop, that is connected to my HDTV via HDMI, the PC just suspends.

Is there any way to set this behaviour?